# List append is overriding previous values with latest value

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, foreach

I have a checkbox where I am trying to add the datafield from rows which have been checked in gridview. Problem is the list is not populating all the values instead it overrides previous value with latest value.

```
public List<int> ModuleEnrollmentList = new List<int>();



protected void ChkSelected_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxCheckBox cbChkBox = sender as ASPxCheckBox;
        GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer container = cbChkBox.NamingContainer as GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer;
        string moduleEnrollmentId = string.Empty;
        if (cbChkBox.Checked)
        {       
            for (int i = 0; i < grvQualificationScheduleDetails.VisibleRowCount; i++)
            {
               
                moduleEnrollmentId = container.KeyValue.ToString();
                AddModuleId(Convert.ToInt32(moduleEnrollmentId));
          
            }
        }
         //AddModuleId(Convert.ToInt32(moduleEnrollmentId));
       

    }


 public void AddModuleId(int mdleEnrollId)
    {
        ModuleEnrollmentList.Add(mdleEnrollId);        
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use your loop variable `i`?

Comment: I was not sure what the better option would be in this case so I went ahead and used loop variable i to loop through the list